# Retrieve latest MongoDB values with aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I need to recover the last values of my collection, but I need to do it with the mongodb aggregation since I have a JOIN with another collection.

This is the code of my query:

I pass an Array with the sensors that I need to recover.

```
function getDataSensorGreenhousetypeFechasJoin (req, res){
  var array = req.params.nombresensores;
  var arr = array.split(',');
  var id_greenhouse = req.params.id_greenhouse;

  Datagreenhouse.aggregate([
  {"$match":{"attrName":{"$in":arr}}},
  {"$sort":{"recvTime":-1}},
  {"$lookup":{
    "from":"sensors",
    "localField":"attrName", // local field in measurements collection
    "foreignField":"name", //foreign field from sensors collection
    "as":"sensor"
  }},
  {"$unwind":"$sensor"},
  {"$addFields":{
    "sensor.attrName":"$attrName",// Add attrName to the sensors
    "sensor.attrValue":"$attrValue",// Add attrValue to the sensors
    "sensor.recvTimeTs":"$recvTimeTs",
    "sensor.recvTime":"$recvTime"
  }},
  {"$group":{
    "_id":"$attrName", // Group by time
    "medidas":{"$push":"$sensor"}, // Collect measurements
    "count":{"$sum":1} // Count measurements
  }},
  {"$limit":1}
  ], (err, DatagreenhouseRecuperado) => {
    if (err) return res.status(500).send({message: 'Error al realizar la peticion' + err})
    if (!DatagreenhouseRecuperado) return res.status(404).send({message: 'Error el usuario no existe'})
    res.status(200).send({DatagreenhouseRecuperado})
    })
}
```

This is the result:

```
{
        "DatagreenhouseRecuperado": [
            {
                "_id": "457",
                "medidas": [
                    {
                        "_id": "5bab51c69a3969055b6bf344",
                        "name": "42-457",
                        "type": "clima",
                        "place": "interior",
                        "img": "assets/img/contrast.png",
                        "name_comun": "Radiación solar",
                        "medida": "W/m²",
                        "usuario": "5bab4aa69a3969055b6bf334",
                        "invernadero": "5bab4dbb9a3969055b6bf339",
                        "__v": 0,
                        "attrName": "42-457",
                        "attrValue": 5.215478125,
                        "recvTimeTs": 1538047310,
                        "recvTime": "2018-09-27T11:21:50.000Z"
                    },
                    {
                        "_id": "5bab4e4d9a3969055b6bf33a",
                        "name": "3-457",
                        "type": "clima",
                        "place": "interior",
                        "img": "assets/img/hum.png",
                        "name_comun": "Hum. Relativa",
                        "medida": "%",
                        "usuario": "5bab4aa69a3969055b6bf334",
                        "invernadero": "5bab4dbb9a3969055b6bf339",
                        "__v": 0,
                        "attrName": "3-457",
                        "attrValue": 57.6,
                        "recvTimeTs": 1538047193,
                        "recvTime": "2018-09-27T11:19:53.000Z"
                    },
                    {
                        "_id": "5bab511e9a3969055b6bf33f",
                        "name": "5-457",
                        "type": "clima",
                        "place": "interior",
                        "img": "assets/img/temp.png",
                        "name_comun": "Temp. Suelo",
                        "medida": "ºC",
                        "usuario": "5bab4aa69a3969055b6bf334",
                        "invernadero": "5bab4dbb9a3969055b6bf339",
                        "__v": 0,
                        "attrName": "5-457",
                        "attrValue": 29.222,
                        "recvTimeTs": 1537984323,
                        "recvTime": "2018-09-26T17:52:03.000Z"
                    },
                    {
                        "_id": "5bab51c69a3969055b6bf344",
                        "name": "42-457",
                        "type": "clima",
                        "place": "interior",
                        "img": "assets/img/contrast.png",
                        "name_comun": "Radiación solar",
                        "medida": "W/m²",
                        "usuario": "5bab4aa69a3969055b6bf334",
                        "invernadero": "5bab4dbb9a3969055b6bf339",
                        "__v": 0,
                        "attrName": "42-457",
                        "attrValue": 137.137,
                        "recvTimeTs": 1537954419,
                        "recvTime": "2018-09-26T09:33:39.000Z"
                    }
                ],
                "count": 24
            }
        ]
    }
```

It is not correct because it shows everything and values with the same name with different dates.

I need the last value that each sensor has.

How can I finish tuning the query?

Thank you.

**> EDIT01**

I have tried several things,

with this code if I get what I need but eliminating the part of the join and it is necessary to have the other fields, my question how can I do the part of the JOIN with this code

```
{"$match":{"attrName":{"$in":arr}}},
  {"$sort":{"recvTime":-1}},
  {"$lookup":{
    "from":"sensors",
    "localField":"attrName", // local field in measurements collection
    "foreignField":"name", //foreign field from sensors collection
    "as":"sensor"
  }},
  {"$unwind":"$sensor"},
  {"$addFields":{
    "sensor.attrName":"$attrName",// Add attrName to the sensors
    "sensor.attrValue":"$attrValue",// Add attrValue to the sensors
    "sensor.recvTimeTs":"$recvTimeTs",
    "sensor.recvTime":"$recvTime"
  }},
  {"$group":{
    "_id":"$attrName", // Group by time
    "attrName":{$last:"$attrName"},
    "attrValue":{$last:"$attrValue"},
    "recvTime":{$last:"$recvTime"},
    "medidas":{"$push":"$sensor",}, // Collect measurements
    "count":{"$sum":1} // Count measurements
  }},
```

I have problems with the push and sensor

> **Edit02**

Hi, My answer has to be something like this:

I need you to only show the last values of the sensor list by their date.

I do not know if this information is enough. Before an aggregation by date, the problem is that some data saved at different times some data does not appear for this reason, I need to show the last saved data of the sensors.

```
{
        "DatagreenhouseRecuperado": [
            {
                "_id": "457",
                "medidas": [
                    {
                        "_id": "5bab51c69a3969055b6bf344",
                        "name": "42-457",
                        "type": "clima",
                        "place": "interior",
                        "img": "assets/img/contrast.png",
                        "name_comun": "Radiación solar",
                        "medida": "W/m²",
                        "usuario": "5bab4aa69a3969055b6bf334",
                        "invernadero": "5bab4dbb9a3969055b6bf339",
                        "__v": 0,
                        "attrName": "42-457",
                        "attrValue": 5.215478125,
                        "recvTimeTs": 1538047310,
                        "recvTime": "2018-09-27T11:21:50.000Z"
                    },
                    {
                        "_id": "5bab51529a3969055b6bf340",
                        "name": "17-457",
                        "type": "clima",
                        "place": "interior",
                        "img": "assets/img/contrast.png",
                        "name_comun": "Rad. Solar PAR",
                        "medida": "W/m²",
                        "usuario": "5bab4aa69a3969055b6bf334",
                        "invernadero": "5bab4dbb9a3969055b6bf339",
                        "__v": 0,
                        "attrName": "17-457",
                        "attrValue": 112.165625,
                        "recvTimeTs": 1538047193,
                        "recvTime": "2018-09-27T11:19:53.000Z"
                    },
                    {
                        "_id": "5bab519d9a3969055b6bf342",
                        "name": "21-457",
                        "type": "clima",
                        "place": "interior",
                        "img": "assets/img/co264.png",
                        "name_comun": "CO2",
                        "medida": "ppm",
                        "usuario": "5bab4aa69a3969055b6bf334",
                        "invernadero": "5bab4dbb9a3969055b6bf339",
                        "__v": 0,
                        "attrName": "21-457",
                        "attrValue": 827.6,
                        "recvTimeTs": 1538047193,
                        "recvTime": "2018-09-27T11:19:53.000Z"
                    },
                    {
                        "_id": "5bab511e9a3969055b6bf33f",
                        "name": "5-457",
                        "type": "clima",
                        "place": "interior",
                        "img": "assets/img/temp.png",
                        "name_comun": "Temp. Suelo",
                        "medida": "ºC",
                        "usuario": "5bab4aa69a3969055b6bf334",
                        "invernadero": "5bab4dbb9a3969055b6bf339",
                        "__v": 0,
                        "attrName": "5-457",
                        "attrValue": 27.844,
                        "recvTimeTs": 1538047193,
                        "recvTime": "2018-09-27T11:19:53.000Z"
                    },
                    {
                        "_id": "5bab4e4d9a3969055b6bf33a",
                        "name": "3-457",
                        "type": "clima",
                        "place": "interior",
                        "img": "assets/img/hum.png",
                        "name_comun": "Hum. Relativa",
                        "medida": "%",
                        "usuario": "5bab4aa69a3969055b6bf334",
                        "invernadero": "5bab4dbb9a3969055b6bf339",
                        "__v": 0,
                        "attrName": "3-457",
                        "attrValue": 57.6,
                        "recvTimeTs": 1538047193,
                        "recvTime": "2018-09-27T11:19:53.000Z"
                    },
                    {
                        "_id": "5bab4f009a3969055b6bf33b",
                        "name": "2-457",
                        "type": "clima",
                        "place": "interior",
                        "img": "assets/img/temp.png",
                        "name_comun": "Temp. Ambiente",
                        "medida": "ºC",
                        "usuario": "5bab4aa69a3969055b6bf334",
                        "invernadero": "5bab4dbb9a3969055b6bf339",
                        "__v": 0,
                        "attrName": "2-457",
                        "attrValue": 32.2,
                        "recvTimeTs": 1538047193,
                        "recvTime": "2018-09-27T11:19:53.000Z"
                    }
                ],
                "count": 24
            }
        ]
    }
```

I am based on this example since it is the same only that it does not have the join

[Ejemplo](https://code.i-harness.com/es/q/1647427)

> **EDIT03**

it works correctly by showing only the last values, but I need only an ID at the beginning and the measurements in Objects as in the structure above.

This is the part of the code that I added as you told me

```
{"$group":{
    "_id":"$id_greenhouse",
    "latest":{"$first":"$$ROOT"},
  }},
 {"$project":{
    "_id":0,
    "id_greenhouse":"$latest.id_greenhouse",
    "attrName":"$latest.attrName",
    "attrValue":"$latest.attrValue",
    "recvTimeTs":"$latest.recvTimeTs",
    "recvTime":"$latest.recvTime"
  }},
```

Result

```
    {
    "DatagreenhouseRecuperado": [
        {
            "_id": "457",
            "medidas": [
                {
                    "_id": "5bab50f09a3969055b6bf33e",
                    "name": "6-457",
                    "type": "fertigation",
                    "place": "interior",
                    "img": "assets/img/hum.png",
                    "name_comun": "Humedad del Suelo",
                    "medida": "%",
                    "usuario": "5bab4aa69a3969055b6bf334",
                    "invernadero": "5bab4dbb9a3969055b6bf339",
                    "__v": 0,
                    "attrName": "6-457",
                    "attrValue": 39.4,
                    "recvTimeTs": 1537954419,
                    "recvTime": "2018-09-28T09:33:39.000Z",
                    "id_greenhouse": "457"
                }
            ],
            "count": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: can you provide sample data?

Comment: That sounds relatively easy to solve once you post some sample input data and the desired result.

Comment: I have added information.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `$group` + `$project` stage after `$sort` and before `$lookup` stage.

Something like

```
 {"$group":{
    "_id":"$attrName",
    "latest":{"$first":"$$ROOT"},
  }},
 {"$project":{
    "_id":0,
    "id_greenhouse":"$latest._id",
    "attrName":"$latest.attrName",
    "attrValue":"$latest.attrValue",
    "recvTimeTs":"$latest.recvTimeTs",
    "recvTime":"$latest.recvTime"
  }}
```

Comment: hello, first of all thanks for the answer is getting closer to what I need.

I have realized that the final result I put is not the correct one, I would only have to leave the ID once with the attrName and then the measures I updated in post with the final result and the new result that I am getting

Comment: I want to add all the medidas within the medidas array and now I create independent objects

Comment: I just realized that if I group it by attrName it is not correct it has to be by id_greenhouse since everyone buys that, otherwise by attrName it groups separately. My problem is that if I do it for id_greenhouse it just shows a record

Comment: You are welcome. This should have worked . Can you add few documents from both collections ? I will verify at my end.